# What is each curly brace standing for when declaring/initializing a struct? (warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces])

Tags: c, struct

I came across the following structure:

```
static struct {
    unsigned char a[5];
} b[] = {       
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {2,2,2,2,2}
};
```

However, if it is being compiled I get the following warning  "warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]".

If I alter it like so:

```
static struct {
    unsigned char a[5];
} b[] = {       
        {{1,1,1,1,1}},
        {{2,2,2,2,2}}
};
```

Then the warning is gone. What is each curly brace standing for after "b[] = " ?
The innermost curly braces are obviously? standing for the initialization of char a[5]. But what are the other braces standing for? Obviously? one of the other curly braces has to account for the structure array b[] but which one? And why is there, as it seems, a third curly brace neccessary and what is it standing for? This confuses me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int a[2] = { 1, 2 };
```

Ok. Now this:

```
int a[2][2] = { { 1, 2 } , { 3, 4 } };
```

Right? `a[0][0] = 1` and `a[0][1] = 2` and `a[1][0] = 3` and `a[1][1] = 4`. `a[0]` is memcmp equal to `(int[]){ 1, 2 }` and `a[1]` is memcmp equal to `(int[]){ 3, 4 }`.

Now this:

```
struct {
     int a[2];
} b = { { 1, 2 } };
```

So the first `{` `}` stand for structure initialization and the inner stand for `b.a` initialization. Now we make an array of structures:

```
struct b_s {
     int a[2];
} b[] = { 
      {
         { 1, 2 },
      },{ 
         { 3, 4, }
      },
};
```

So the first braces stand for array `b[]` initialization. The second one are for structure `b[0]` to initialize. The third one are to initialize the `b[0].a` array.

The `b[0]` is memcmp equal to `&(struct b_s){ {1, 2 } }`. The `b[0].a` is memcmp equal to `(int[2]){ 1, 2 }`. The `b[0].a[0]` is equal to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Each brace corresponds to the start of a subobject (an object inside an aggregate object, such as an array or structure).

`b[]` is an array, so the first brace introduces elements of the array.

Each `b` is a structure, so the next brace introduces members of the structure.

The member `a` inside `b` is an array, so the next braces introduces elements of that array.

Answer (score 1):

`{1,1,1,1,1}` - The five elements of an array.

`{{1,1,1,1,1}}` - That's how you initialize a struct with a field which is an array of five `int`s in this case.

`{{{1,1,1,1,1}}, {{2,2,2,2,2}}}` - This is an array of two elements. Where each element is an instance of a struct as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You have an **array** of **structs** containing **arrays**. Three pairs of braces.

Answer (score 0):

```
static struct {
    unsigned char a[5];
} b[] = {                 // array b
        {                 // struct
        {                 // array a
          1,1,1,1,1}},
        {                 // another struct
        {2,2,2,2,2}}
};
```